# Nested dictionary in a list received from google api not getting parsed

Tags: python, parsing, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been spending the past days trying to retrieve all of the `"dateTime"` values from `"start"` and `"end"` from this nested dictionary in a nested list(s) with every kind of looping, yet I haven't been successful. Does anyone know how I shall approach it?

```
AllCals =     [
        {
            "accessRole": "reader",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "Holidays in Canada",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-09T20:44:17.000Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "Business Sim",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-10-26T19:23:14.031Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "COMN",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-05T20:15:35.506Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-11-09T16:45:47.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T18:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "displayName": "Predictive",
                        "email": "@group.calendar.google.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T17:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "Group call",
                    "updated": "2020-11-10T00:13:33.387Z"
                },
                {
                    "created": "2020-11-11T02:02:03.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T22:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "displayName": "Predictive",
                        "email": "@group.calendar.google.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T21:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "predictive part",
                    "updated": "2020-11-11T02:02:03.410Z"
                }
            ],
            "kind": "calendar#",
            "nextSyncToken": "-=",
            "summary": "Predictive",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-11T02:02:03.410Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "description": "",
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-09-23T02:48:00.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "date": "2020-11-10"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "displayName": "Real Estate",
                        "email": "@group.calendar.google.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": false
                    },
                    "sequence": 3,
                    "start": {
                        "date": "2020-11-09"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "Assignment 3",
                    "updated": "2020-09-26T17:36:50.714Z"
                }
            ],
            "kind": "#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "Real Estate",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-06T06:24:35.930Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-09-30T19:24:53.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T02:00:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "displayName": "Reading",
                        "email": "@group.calendar.google.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "originalStartTime": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T01:00:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "recurringEventId": "",
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T01:00:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "Reading",
                    "updated": "2020-09-30T19:24:53.912Z"
                }
            ],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "Reading",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-09-30T19:24:53.912Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-11-11T00:09:57.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com"
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T20:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "displayName": "ToDo",
                        "email": "@group.calendar.google.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T19:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "",
                    "updated": "2020-11-11T00:09:57.152Z"
                }
            ],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "-=",
            "summary": "ToDo",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-11T00:09:57.152Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [
                {
                    "method": "popup",
                    "minutes": 30
                }
            ],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [
                {
                    "created": "2020-09-29T03:29:51.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T14:30:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "etag": "\"\"",
                    "htmlLink": "",
                    "iCalUID": ".com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "originalStartTime": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T11:30:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "recurringEventId": "",
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 0,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T11:30:00-05:00",
                        "timeZone": "America/Toronto"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "ENTR 4700",
                    "updated": "2020-09-29T03:29:51.740Z"
                },
                {
                    "created": "2020-11-10T05:39:09.000Z",
                    "creator": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "end": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T11:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "etag": "",
                    "htmlLink": "",
                    "iCalUID": "@google.com",
                    "id": "",
                    "kind": "calendar#event",
                    "organizer": {
                        "email": "@gmail.com",
                        "self": true
                    },
                    "reminders": {
                        "useDefault": true
                    },
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "start": {
                        "dateTime": "2020-11-10T10:30:00-05:00"
                    },
                    "status": "confirmed",
                    "summary": "Pick a term sheet ",
                    "updated": "2020-11-10T05:39:12.662Z"
                }
            ],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "ENTR 4700",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-10T06:12:07.093Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "=",
            "summary": "Programming",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-08T01:45:49.847Z"
        },
        {
            "accessRole": "owner",
            "defaultReminders": [],
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "items": [],
            "kind": "calendar#events",
            "nextSyncToken": "",
            "summary": "Alexa",
            "timeZone": "America/Toronto",
            "updated": "2020-11-08T16:37:12.291Z"
        }
    ]

    print(type(AllCals))
    <class 'list'>
```

Unfortunately, google's calendar API doesn't provide all the events of the user even when `"CalendarId"` is set [to](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) `'primary'` which has been an issue amongst [developers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135376206). Therefore, I have no choice but to extract each calendar of the user, merge, and then parse.

**The ultimate goal**: Retrieve the user's duration of events from the calendar.

```
events = events_result.get('items', [])
Ids = [item['id'] for item in events]
AllCals = [service.events().list(calendarId=id, timeMin=yesterdayy, timeMax = utc_dt,singleEvents=True,orderBy='updated').execute() for id in Ids ]
```

Comment: What exactly do you have trouble with? Parsing the ISO strings?

Comment: yeah, I can't retrieve the "dateTime" value from the list.

Comment: There are multiple "dateTime" values, what are you trying to achieve? Looping over all items from all calenders and extracting the start and end times seems trivial, so I guess you are looking for something else if professional developers weren't able to help you. Maybe you could add an example of the desired output/result.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I am trying to retrieve every "dateTime" value from the dictionary. It might not be the most professional way, but that's the only way that comes to my mind for retrieving each of the user's events' duration from the calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data you showed seems to be JSON, but I'll assume you have a list of dicts, each with a key "items" holding an array of calendar items, each of which has keys "start" and "end", each containing a dict with either a key "date" or "dateTime" containing an ISO date string.

I still don't know what you are going to do with it, but if I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve the durations of all calendar's items.

```py
from datetime import datetime

# AllCals = ...

for calendar in AllCals:
    for item in calendar["items"]:
        # this could probably be done more elegantly. you basically want item["start"]["date"] or item["start"]["dateTime"], whichever is present
        item_start = item["start"]
        item_start_string = item_start["date"] if "date" in item_start else item_start["dateTime"]
        start_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(item_start_string)

        item_end = item["end"]
        item_end_string = item_end["date"] if "date" in item_end else item_end["dateTime"]
        end_datetime = datetime.fromisoformat(item_end_string)

        duration = end_datetime - start_datetime
        print(f"{item['summary']}: {duration}")
```

With your example data, this prints:

```
Group call: 1:00:00
predictive part: 1:00:00
Assignment 3: 1 day, 0:00:00
Reading: 1:00:00
: 1:00:00
ENTR 4700: 3:00:00
Pick a term sheet : 1:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! @danzel That's exactly what I was looking for, MVP.